# is there any elastic search playground available in online ? with specific use-case scenarios

Tags: database, elasticsearch

is there any elastic search playground available online? with specific use-case scenarios.

where I can find it.

if it does not mean, where I can find the use-case based data(large-scale).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The site [searchly](http://www.searchly.com/) offers a free plan which is limited to 20MB storage and 2 indices.